# how face recognition works in real time

Tags: algorithm, image-recognition

There are many applications to recognize similar faces. The most popular is **Picasa**. How do these applications do the following?

1) Detect face

2) Check for similar in database.

Comment: I only see a statement, not a question. What do you want to know? What is the problem, you're trying to solve? What have you tried, where did you fail?

Comment: May I suggest that you do some research on face recognition? Noone but the actual developers of the applications you have in mind can possibly answer your question without reverse engineering them. Is this really what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would read [this paper](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/EE148-2005-Spring/pprs/viola04ijcv.pdf)  "Robust Real-Time Face Detection" to get started
also [this one is interesting](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~gregory/papers/fg02gender.pdf)